# ASP.NET Identity RTM and its version

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

ASP.NET Identity nighlty packages are now available on MyGet as per this post.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/09/asp-net-identity-nuget-packages-for-the-nightly-builds-are-available-on-myget.aspx

But, I found the version coming up in nightly build is "1.1.0-alpha1-131011", that seems to be after the version 1 RTM. Or the RTM will be of version 1.1?

When the ASP.NET Identity RTM will be released?

Comment: This exact question would be better suited for the application developers. But if they are following the [Nuget versioning](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning) pattern, and [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/), 1.1.0-alpha would indicate it's the alpha version of 1.1, and things will eventually released as version 1.1.0

Comment: Thanks Steven, my understanding is the same. Still thought RTM may be in QA with v1.0 as v1.0-rc is already released.

Comment: V1.0 RTM will release when Visual Studio 2013 RTM will be released. 1.1.0-alpha1-131011 is a newer version greater than v1.0

Comment: Is there anyway to download the RTM version?

Comment: I could download the RTM version last released on 30 Sept 2013 from MyGet.org site after reviewing its RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

So 1.0 RTM is effectively already done, so the nightly builds are from the 1.1 branch.  There's just this short window between 1.0-RTM going live where there's no where to get it anymore since the nightly branch got switched over.